# Need to find the datediff between more then two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table I need to search the datediff thats higher then xx days between more then two dates.

The table looks like this:

```
ID  DATE
1   2001-09-27
1   2002-02-11
1   2002-11-29
1   2003-11-24
1   2004-03-08
2   2003-11-24
2   2003-11-24
2   2004-11-24
3   2006-11-24
3   2007-11-24
```

I need it to show:

```
ID  DATE        DIF
1   2001-09-27  137       (DATEDIFF(day,'2001-09-27','2002-02-11'))
1   2002-02-11  291       (DATEDIFF(day,'2002-02-11','2002-11-29'))
1   2002-11-29  360       (DATEDIFF(day,'2002-11-29','2003-11-24'))
1   2003-11-24  AND SO ON..
1   2004-03-08
2   2003-11-24
2   2003-11-24
2   2004-11-24
3   2006-11-24
3   2007-11-24
```

So if the ID is the same I want to check the first date to the second date, then the second date to the third and so on.

Comment: you need to apply an order to your data via row_number() then you can use a self join via a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **(Edited for Duplicate Dates)**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[DATE] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (1,'2001-09-27')
,(1,'2002-02-11')
,(1,'2002-11-29')
,(1,'2003-11-24')
,(1,'2004-03-08')
,(2,'2003-11-24')
,(2,'2003-11-24')
,(2,'2004-11-24')
,(3,'2006-11-24')
,(3,'2007-11-24')

Select A.*
      ,[Diff]   = IsNull(DateDiff(DAY,A.[Date],B.[Date]),0) 
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (Select Date=min(Date) From @YourTable Where ID=A.ID and Date>A.Date) B
 Order By A.ID,A.Date
```

**Returns**

```
ID  DATE        Diff
1   2001-09-27  137
1   2002-02-11  291
1   2002-11-29  360
1   2003-11-24  105
1   2004-03-08  0
2   2003-11-24  366   -- Notice Dupe Date
2   2003-11-24  366   -- Notice Dupe Date
2   2004-11-24  0
3   2006-11-24  365
3   2007-11-24  0
```

Comment: @MrRAW Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012+ has `LEAD()`.  You can emulate this using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, t1.date, tnext.date) as diff
from t t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.id = t.id and
            t2.date > t.date
      order by t2.date
     ) tnext;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  n.ID
        ,n.DATE
        ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, n.date, r.date), 0) AS DIF
FROM (SELECT    ID
                ,date
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY Date) AS number
    FROM table) n
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   ID
                        ,date
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY Date) AS number
        FROM table) r
        ON n.number + 1 = r.number
            AND n.ID = r.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gordon's example of `LEAD()`, there is also a `LAG()` function which, when used with a `CASE WHEN` statement, I think presents an elegant solution not yet shown.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TEMP;
WITH cte (ID, Date_Changed) AS
    (
    SELECT 1, '2001-09-27' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2002-02-11' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2002-11-29' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2003-11-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2004-03-08' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2003-11-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2003-11-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2004-11-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2006-11-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2007-11-24' 
    )
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM cte

SELECT *
    ,CASE WHEN lag(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID, Date_Changed) = ID 
    THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,lag(Date_Changed) OVER (ORDER BY ID, Date_Changed),Date_Changed)
    ELSE 0 
    END AS 'DaysBetween'
FROM #TEMP
```